# Azure Cloud Shell immediately exiting

Tags: azure, azureshell

I am getting kicked out of the Azure cloud shell immediately when attempting to use it in a terminal window on Windows. (It has worked in the past) Why might this be happening?

Here is my session:

```
Tenant 0: XXXXXXXX Directory (xxxxxxx.com)
Please enter the desired tenant number.
Enter n to login with a new account
Enter r to remove the above saved connection settings.
> 0
Requesting a cloud shell instance...
Succeeded.
Requesting a terminal (this might take a while)...

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.
```

Note: I am able to successfully use the cloud shell via the portal in my web browser.

Comment: Please try these steps and let me know if it got fixed
Update the Azure CLI to the latest version using `az upgrade`.
Try to reauthenticate using [az login](https://i.imgur.com/yzTdMk9.png) to refresh your session tokens
If issue persists, run the Azure CLI in debug mode using `az --debug` to get more detailed output that might help identify the issue.

also refer to this [Similar issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/782342/azure-cloud-shell-failed-to-request-a-terminal)

Comment: @Arko the issue is with Azur Cloud Shell, not Azure CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely remedied by updating Windows Terminal.